# Appending "<>" to each item in a list

Tags: python, append

I have this code in Python 2.7 I've been working on, and i got stuck.
I'm trying to go from
`["bob","sally","jim"])`
to
`'bob<>sally<>jim'`

Here's what i have so far.

```
def long_winded(my_str):
  result = []
  for i in my_str:
    result += i + "<>"
  return result

print long_winded(["sally","bob","jim"])
```

Answer (score 9):

You can just use the [`.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) string method:

```
my_lst = ['sally', 'bob', 'jim']
result = '<>'.join(my_lst)
```

And, of course you can always wrap all of this up in a function, but you probably don't need to:

```
def long_winded(lst):
  return '<>'.join(lst)

print long_winded(['sally', 'bob', 'jim'])
```

Comment: that worked, thanks! i'm learning python, and it can get stressful

Comment: Well, you could also make it a function by `long_winded = '<>'.join` :p

Comment: @JonClements -- I thought about putting that as part of my answer (I left the same comment on the other answer), but . . . It seemed like it would be more confusing than it's worth and I'm not sure how I'd feel if I saw that in actual code . . .  On the other hand, it is quite fun (and useful!) that python lets you do stuff like that.  I've been writing some JS lately and it annoys me to no end how much I need to `.bind(this)` :-/

Comment: @mgilson oops didn't see the comment on Suraj's post - must be the hive-mind humour kicking in about the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in `join` method...

```
def long_winded(my_str):
    return '<>'.join(my_str)
```

Comment: It's not exactly an _operator_... _method_ is probably a more appropriate term.  And, just for fun, `long_winded = '<>'.join` would even work :-)